# Installing Rails using gem gets stuck at "parsing documentation"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems, centos, rvm

Whenever I install Rails on my VPS, it gets stuck at the last part

```
gem install rails
```

> .. Parsing documentation for rails-4.0.3
>
> .. Installing ri documentation for rails-4.0.3

I have to `CTRL` and `C` and then repeat the command for install to finish.

What might be the problem?

It gets stuck there.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but you can `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc` to bypass the documentation install.

Comment: Ah thanks! Will try that next time I run a new VPS!

Comment: This ri documentation install takes more time than the entire process of installing ruby, or the other packages of rails together while using 100% of a core. Something is clearly wrong. But after ~10 minute or so it finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing document process takes a lot of time.
I think process was working. If you're using Ubuntu, use the `top` command or `ps aux` to see the process is working or not.